# Using PAM config and SSHD config together

Tags: ssh, opensuse, sshd, pam

I have a server running openSUSE which uses `PAM` config files for authentication/lockout/password policy etc. I now need to limit the allowed list of `SSH` ciphers. Normally I'd just do this in the `sshd_config` file.

However, if PAM is enabled will the ciphers I list in `sshd_config` be ignored or used in addition to `PAM`? Or should I be settings these in the `/etc/pam.d/sshd` config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, if PAM is enabled will the ciphers I list in sshd_config be ignored or used in addition to PAM? Or should I be settings these in the `/etc/pam.d/sshd` config?

In `/etc/pam.d/sshd` you don't specify any ciphers. It is used for the management of user sessions and login. The ciphers specified in `sshd_config` will be used regardless PAM.

Comment: Thank you very much. I thought this would be the case but I couldn't find solid confirmation of this online. Appreciate it.